# Azure Key Vault - programmatic creation

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-keyvault

How can an Azure KeyVault be created programmatically using C# in a .NET core app?
I have seen examples of writing to and reading from the key vault after
it is provisioned but not on creating the kv itself.

Answer (score 3):

Use the method [`VaultsOperationsExtensions.CreateOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.keyvault.vaultsoperationsextensions.createorupdate?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_KeyVault_VaultsOperationsExtensions_CreateOrUpdate_Microsoft_Azure_Management_KeyVault_IVaultsOperations_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_KeyVault_Models_VaultCreateOrUpdateParameters_) from the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault` namespace.

Here you can check all the methods in the VaultsOperationsExtensions class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.keyvault.vaultsoperationsextensions?view=azure-dotnet