# Create Azure Key Vault Using .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to create azure key vault using .net core 2.1 with OpenIdConnect.

**What I have tried :-**
I have tried to refer following stack-overflow already question-answer

1. [Creating Azure Key Vault using .NET assembly (Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276458/creating-azure-key-vault-using-net-assembly-microsoft-azure-keyvault)
2. [Azure Key Vault - programmatic creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198357/azure-key-vault-programmatic-creation)

and Others

Nuget package :- Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault

**Code :-**

```
private async Task AddKeyVaultAsync()
    {
        var clientId = "xxxx"; 
        var tenantId = "xxxx";
        var clientSecret = "xxxx";
        var objectId = "xxxx";
        var subscriptionId = "xxx";

        // The resource group to create the vault in.
        string resourceGroupName = "Vaults-Resource-Group";
        // The name of the vault to create.
        string vaultName = "web-app-01-vault";
        var parameters = new VaultCreateOrUpdateParameters()
        {
            Location = "southeast asia",
            Properties = new VaultProperties()
            {
                TenantId = Guid.Parse(tenantId),
                AccessPolicies = new List<AccessPolicyEntry>()
                {
                    new AccessPolicyEntry
                    {
                        TenantId = Guid.Parse(tenantId),
                        ObjectId = objectId,
                         Permissions = new Permissions
                            {
                              Secrets = new List<string> { "all" },
                              Keys = new string[] { "all" }
                            }
                    }
                }       
            }
        };

        //problem in following line
        var tokenCredentials = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, token);

        var keyVaultManagementClient = new KeyVaultManagementClient(tokenCredentials);
        // Create the vault
       await keyVaultManagementClient.Vaults.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, vaultName, parameters);

    }
```

but I am stuck at

```
 //problem in the following line
        var tokenCredentials = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, token);
```

How can i create token(parameter in TokenCloudCredentials) and TokenCloudCredentials?
Which Nuget package shall i use to create TokenCloudCredentials?

I have also tried to use :-

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();
```

to create KeyVaultManagementClient. but I am not sure that how can do it?

Is there any other(better) way to create KeyVaultManagementClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shows how to get an access token using client credential flow.

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
           .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "{tenantID}")
           .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
           .Build();

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

var token = result.accessToken;
```

For more details, see [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows#code-snippet).

---

**Update:**

The [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-authentication/blob/master/KeyVaultAuthSample.cs#L85) of creating key vault using .net core 2.1

Comment: Which nuget package needed for TokenCloudCredentials?

Comment: @HarishShisode package `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common` is needed for TokenCloudCredentials

Comment: Hi, above mentioned package is not compatible with .net core 2.1.

Comment: @HarishShisode [TokenCloudCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt167728(v=azure.100)) is used for the older version and have no longer updating. So if you want to create key vault using .net core 2.1, you could follow this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-authentication/blob/master/KeyVaultAuthSample.cs#L85).

Comment: Thanks! above sample help me to solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

- **Before accessing Key Vault from code ensure that MSI(Managed Service Identity) is configured in Azure**
- To enable the use of Azure Key Vault you need to install below
  packages.

```cs
PM> Install-Package Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault
PM> Install-Package Azure.Identity
PM> Install-Package Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets
```

- Enable App Configuration in Program.cs — Update the
  CreateWebHostBuilder method to use App Configuration by calling the
  config.AddAzureAppConfiguration() method.

```cs
#region Imports
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
#endregion

namespace AzureKeyVaultLabs.Web
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    var settings = config.Build();

                    if (!context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        var keyVaultEndpoint = settings["AzureKeyVaultEndpoint"];

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                        {
                            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                            config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                        }
                    }
           }
      }
```

- For Azure Function Apps

```cs
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            if (builder != null)
            {
                //give your app configuration store endpoint
                string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppConfigurationConnectionString");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
                {
                    builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(connectionString);
                }

                var settings = builder.ConfigurationBuilder.Build();
                var keyVaultEndpoint = settings["VaultName"];// Add key vault name in configuration
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                {
                    builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                        .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                        .AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyVaultEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential())
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();
                }
            }
        }
```